# Using sed to modify an undefined string

Tags: text-processing, sed

I need to use sed to modify a document called "case" with the lines example="value" where value can take any 2 o 3 characters integer, for example:

```
example=55
example=777
otherthing=anothervalue
```

I want to use sed to modify both of the example lines into two lines called  `example=000`

I have tried to use

```
sed -i -e "s/example=*/example=000/g" case
```

to modify them both at the same time, but obviously it did not worked. What I need to know is how to make sed take any 2 or 3 characters after the `=`

Comment: From your question it sounds like the problem is modifying 2 matching lines at the same time - did you have a script that modifies 1 line?

Answer (score 7):

You're confusing the different meanings of `*` for [Shell Filename Expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_08) and [Posix Basic Regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) (`BRE`).

In Regex, `*` is the quantifier for the character in front of it, so `=*` means 0 or more occurrences of `=`. If you want "any number of any character", use `.*`.

```
sed -i -e 's/example=.*/example=000/' case
```

Some more hints:

- You can leave out the `g` modifier, as your string likely appears only once per line.
- If you **don't** want to also match `another_example=value`, use `^example=.*` to make sure that `example` is at the start of the line.
- Instead of `.` for any character, you can use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]]` to match only numbers.
- Instead of `*`, you can use `+` quantifier, that means *1 or more characters* (must be escaped to `\+` for `BRE` in GNU `sed` or written as `\{1,\}` for general `sed`).

---

To match only 2 or 3 characters, you can do

```
sed -i -e 's/example=.\{2,3\}/example=000/' case
```

or using Extended Regex (`ERE`) (`sed -E`):

```
sed -i -E -e 's/example=.{2,3}/example=000/' case
```

Comment: +1.   The OP could use `^example=[0-9]\{1,\}` or `^example=[[:digit:]]\{1,\}` instead of `.` to limit the match to digits. Also, some versions of sed (e.g. GNU sed) understand `\+` in BRE to mean `one-or-more`, same as `+` in ERE (this is **not** POSIX BRE, but neither is `|` or `\|` for alternation).   e.g.  `^example=[[:digit:]]\+`.  Personally, I mostly use `sed -E` for ERE except for the most trivial of regexes.

Comment: Thanks, added that to my hints.